# Add my windows program to startup registry with file writing

Tags: python, windows, startup

I have got python gui(tkinter) application for windows. I want add it to autostart with registry. Registry key is exists:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "My App" /t REG_SZ /F /D "C:\path_to_file\1.exe"
```

With windows load application starts, but fails with "[Error 5]" error on code:

```
os.mkdir(path)
```

Manual start by double click on exe works fine. How can I add my program to windows autostart for clients?

ps: tested on windows 7 x64, python 2.7

Comment: What's `path`, a directory relative to the current working directory? If so, what's `os.getcwd()`? It's probably the System32 directory. When you run it from Explorer, the working directory is the executable's directory.

Comment: Thank you for feedback. Path is relative. I think it may be a problem. I will check it soon